# Whirlpool dishwasher having issues, what would cause these symptoms?

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Whirlpool dishwasher (type 575-0). Over the weekend, the dishwasher control buttons simply stopped working. No LEDs came on when the button was pushed, dishwasher didn't start, nothing.

Yesterday I disassembled the dishwasher, reset all the connections, and clean up the door switch. After reassembling the dishwasher and turning power back on, exactly one light came on (the sani-rinse). Thinking it was just the lights, I pushed start and when I closed the door, there was a mechanical grinding sound. I don't think it was the integrated disposal, it sounded more like a pump or valve. It definitely didn't sound good. After that happened, the board was once more dead. After resetting the power, again the single light. I tried putting it into diagnostic mode, but nothing happened.

Does this seem like a control board issue? With the odd sound, I'm wondering if one of the pumps/values is causing a problem that breaks the controls. The control board costs 1/3 of the amount of a new dishwasher, so I'm not going to replace it unless I know that is the problem.

Does anyone have any ideas on what the issue could be?

[image: button layout]
[image: model information]

Comment: Sounds like a bad logic board.

Comment: wild guessing: could be something shorting out (tripping a shutoff); could be a fried circuit or a bad other board. Either way, probably time for a new dishwasher if this one is already several years old.

Comment: A short seems to have won the day. This afternoon I started smelling burnt plastic. After shutting off the breaker to the dishwasher, it went away. I'm hopeful that the short isn't in the wall, but is instead in the dishwasher.

Answer (score 0):

After smelling burnt plastic for a few hours, I can safely say it was a short.

Comment: A pump that is stuck will draw locked rotor current , this is much like a short and will cause the burning smell as the windings over heat.

Comment: Possibly something stuck in the grinder, or a stuck water pump (as Ed suggested)?  Also check for a stuck float switch. It sounds like the washer thinks there is still water that needs to be drained but the pump can't turn for some reason.